# Rails App crashes when Authorizing OmniAuth and Devise on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I am trying to allow users to authorize their account to access Github and Angel.co. My request goes out but I keep getting an error and the page crashes. Please assist me in trouble shooting this issue.

#### omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def all
    #raise request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_yaml
    account = Account.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
     if account.persisted?
       sign_in_and_redirect account, notice: "Signed in!"
     else
       session["devise.account_attributes"] = account.attributes
       redirect_to new_account_registration_url
     end
  end

  alias_method :facebook, :all  
  alias_method :github, :all
  alias_method :angellist, :all


end
```

#### accounts.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable, :validatable, :trackable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable #, :confirmable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :authorizations    

 def self.from_omniauth(auth, current_account)
   authorization = Authorization.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid.to_s, token: auth.credentials.token, secret: auth.credentials.secret).first_or_initialize
     if authorization.account.blank?
       account = current_account.nil? ? Account.where('email = ?', auth["info"]["email"]).first : current_account
       if account.blank?
        account = Account.new
        account.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,10]
        account.email = auth.info.email
        auth.provider == "github" ?  account.save(validate: false) :  account.save
      end
      authorization.account.user.name = auth.info.full_name
      authorization.account_id = account.id
      authorization.save
    end
    authorization.account
  end


  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
     if session["devise.account_attributes"]
        new(session["devise.account_attributes"], without_protection: true) do |account|
        account.attributes = params
        account.valid?
     end
     else
      super
     end
  end

   def password_required?
    super 
   end
```

#### edit.html.erb

```
<% ['github', 'angellist', 'facebook' ].each do |provider| %>
              <% if @account.authorizations.pluck(:provider).include?(provider.to_s) %>
                   <%= provider.to_s.titleize %> Connected
                <% else %>
              <%= link_to "Sign in with #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path('account', provider) %>
              <% end %>
                <br/>
          <% end %>
        </div>
     </div>
```

#### ERROR

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)):
app/models/account.rb:21:in `from_omniauth'
app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:5:in `all'
```

Comment: Well, what is the error?

Comment: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)):
app/models/account.rb:21:in `from_omniauth'
app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:5:in `all'

Comment: Well, that error is pretty self-explanatory. On your `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` file, in line 5, you are calling the method `from_omniauth` with only one argument when it is expecting to receive two arguments. You need to pass the `current_account` to that method.

Comment: Have you upgrade to rails 4.1.5, this seams to make that problem appear